# Image filter kernel edge problems (Reflect values on edge)

Tags: c++, image, algorithm, opencv

I want to handle some edge problems that occur when using differently sized kernels on images.

First of all: I know there are prebuilt options in opencv for handling these cases but since this is an excercise for university I am not allowed to use those. [Edge handling in OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=copymakeborder#copymakeborder)

Bascially I want to achieve something like this (letters for easier readability)

```
    a b c        e d e
    d e f        b a b
    g h i        e d e
```

On the left is an example set of values and on the right we are looking at the letter **a** as the center of our kernel which has the size of 3x3. Now I want to reflect and skip the letter that is right on the edge of the image (and also reflect without skipping but thats not very nice to visualize with a 3x3 kernel)

Obviously one can just go ahead and make up like 6 different if/else cases to solve this but there has to be a better and easier solution that i just can't come up with and i have also not found while searching.

This is how i did my other edge modes for example (see mode_clamp, i am looking for a solution of this sort):

```
uchar get_edge_intensity(cv::Mat m, int y, int x, int edge_mode, double edge_intensity) {
    uchar result = 0;

    switch (edge_mode) {
      case MODE_NULL:
        break;
      case MODE_CLAMP:        
        result = m.at<uchar>( std::min(std::max(0, y), m.rows - 1), 
                              std::min(std::max(0, x), m.cols - 1));
        break;
      case MODE_MIRROR:
        // TODO
        break;
      case MODE_MIRROR_SKIP:
        // TODO
        break;
      case MODE_CONSTANT:
        result = clamp(PIXEL_MAX_VALUE * edge_intensity);
        break;
    }

    return result;
  }
```

*clamp(double value)* just clamps a given double value to 0-255 and returns it as uchar if someone needs to know this